# Kendo grid with dropdown column does not assign integer value

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'd soo appreciate if someone could suggest on my problem.
I have a model containing a collection:

```
public class Customer
{
   public Customer()
   {
       this.CustomerAddresses = new HashSet<CustomerAddress>();
   }
  //..properties
   public virtual ICollection<CustomerAddress> CustomerAddresses {get; set;}
}
```

In my 'Create' view I have a grid with incell editing, that allows me to store the collection of `CustomerAddress` and then pass to the controller along with `Customer` model:

```
@model Customer
 //Customer inputs...

@( Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.CustomerAddresses)
    .Name("CustomerAddresses")
    .ToolBar(toolbar => { toolbar.Create(); })
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.AddressID).Hidden();       
        columns.Bound(p => p.Type)             //Foreign key of type string
               .EditorTemplateName("DropDownTemplate")
               .EditorViewData(new { ddname = "Type" })
               .ClientTemplate("#= Type #" +
        "<input type='hidden' name='CustomerAddresses[#= index(data)#].Type' value='#= Type #'  />"); 

        columns.Bound(p => p.Region)          //Foreign key of type int?
               .EditorTemplateName("DropDownTemplate")
               .EditorViewData(new { ddname = "Region" })
               .ClientTemplate("#= Region #" +
        "<input type='hidden' name='CustomerAddresses[#= index(data)#].Region' value='#= Region #'  />"); 

    })    
    .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
    .DataSource(dataSource =>
     dataSource.Ajax()
    .Model(model =>
    {
        model.Id(u => u.AddressID);

    })
    ))
```

DropDownTemplate:

```
@if (ViewData["ddname"] == "Region")
{      
     @Html.Kendo().ComboBox().Name(ViewData["ddname"].ToString())
                  .BindTo(SelectListProvider.GetCatalog<Region>())
}
else
{   
     @Html.Kendo().ComboBox().Name(ViewData["ddname"].ToString())
                  .BindTo(SelectListProvider.GetCatalog<AddressType>())
}
```

The problem is when I select some item from dropdown for `Region` integer column and press outside the cell it doesn't assign selected value to the grid column. I see an empty cell.
However, when I select in `Type` cell which is string and press outside I see the selected value.

What am I doing wrong? What's the problem with int column?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I finally figured it out. Instead of templates I use foreign keys, as well as hidden fields for the same columns:

```
 columns.ForeignKey(p => p.Type, someselectlist, "Value", "Text");
 columns.ForeignKey(p => p.Region, anotherselectlist, "Value", "Text");

 columns.Bound(p => p.Type).ClientTemplate("#= Type #" +
        "<input type='hidden' name='Addresses[#= index(data)#].Type' value='#= Type #'  />").Hidden();
 columns.Bound(p => p.Region).ClientTemplate("#= Region #" +
        "<input type='hidden' name='Addresses[#= index(data)#].Region' value='#= Region #'  />").Hidden();
```

GridForeignKey.cshtml

```
 Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(m => m)
        .BindTo((SelectList)ViewData[ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName("") + "_Data"])
        .HtmlAttributes(new { data_value_primitive = true })
```

Now, It works as I wanted, and all values are sumbitting to the controller.